# How can I modify the Office Custom Task Pane menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-addins, customtaskpane

I'm making a Custom Task Pane for MS Word using Visual Studio (C#), and would like to add an option to the drop-down menu that, as far as I can tell, appears on all such task-panes. [This is the menu I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypzsi.png)

Is there a way to add an option to the default "Move, Size, Close"?

Comment: An update: I've been looking into this for a couple of days now and can't find any way to do it; nor have I found any references to anyone else being able to modify the menu. That's not say that it's impossible, but I'm not going to be spending any more time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no, you cannot do this.

The Office add-in model is such that you only control the web application portion of the experience. Everything else is controlled by Office.

With the new web-based add-in model, you have much less control over Office itself than previous models.